# Full Page JS not Resizing Properly

Tags: jquery

Ok.. so I built this page: http://stpaullux18re.wpengine.com/ with the jquery plugin Full Page js. Right now I have it set to disengage below 700px wide. What I'm struggling with is if the user resizes the window it goes all wonky. I tried the following code, but it just breaks the page. Any thoughts for me on how to implement resize so it resizes gracefully?

```
if ($(window).width() > 700) {
$( window ).resize(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //Navigation

    menu: '#menu',
    lockAnchors: false,
    anchors:['Welcome', 'Distinctive', 'Neighborhood', 'Gallery'],
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    navigationTooltips: ['Welcome', 'Distinctive', 'Neighborhood', 'Gallery'],
    showActiveTooltip: false,
    slidesNavigation: true,
    slidesNavPosition: 'middle',

    //Scrolling
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    autoScrolling: true,
    fitToSection: false,
    fitToSectionDelay: 400,
    scrollBar: true,
    easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    easingcss3: 'ease',
    loopBottom: false,
    loopTop: false,
    loopHorizontal: true,
    continuousVertical: false,
    continuousHorizontal: false,
    scrollHorizontally: false,
    interlockedSlides: false,
    dragAndMove: false,
    offsetSections: false,
    resetSliders: false,
    fadingEffect: true,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    scrollOverflowReset: false,
    scrollOverflowOptions: null,
    touchSensitivity: 15,
    normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
    bigSectionsDestination: null,

    //Accessibility
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    animateAnchor: true,
    recordHistory: true,

    //Design
    controlArrows: true,
    verticalCentered: true,
    fixedElements: '#standard, .fTab, footer',
    parallax: true,
    parallaxOptions: {type: 'cover', percentage: 62, property: 'translate'},

    //Custom selectors
    sectionSelector: '.section',
    slideSelector: '.slide',

    lazyLoading: true,

});
}
```

}